# Build a binary tree from an infix expression without using a stack

Tags: c++, algorithm

Recently I wrote an algorithm to `convert an infix expression to a binary tree without using any stack`. However, as I search on web, I find the algorithms described there are all based on stack(or recursion).

So I begin to worry about the correctness about my algorithm, though I cannot prove
it's incorrect yet.

***Question***

Do you know whether it's technically possible to convert it without any stack or not?  Is my algorithm wrong?

***Short description***

It's based on:

1. An operand in an infix expression belongs to either the right child of the operator in front of it, or the left child of the operator behind it.
2. If an operator `OP2` has higher precedence than its preceding operator `OP1`, the previous operand `x` becomes the left child of `OP2`, and `OP2` becomes the right child of `OP1`.
3. If an operator `OP2` has lower precedence than its preceding operator `OP1`, the previous operand `x` becomes the right child of `OP1`. Go up the tree from `OP1`, compare the precedence of each ancestor of `OP1` with that of `OP2` until `OP2` <= ancestor `OP`. Then `OP2` becomes the right child of `OP`.

***The program***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Node{
   // store operator or operand
   string data;
   // only valid for operator
   int precedence;
   struct Node* parent;
   struct Node* left;
   struct Node* right;
}CNode, *PNode;

PNode CreateNode(const string& x)
{
   PNode p = new CNode;
   p->parent = p->left = p->right = NULL;
   p->data = x;
   return p;
}

bool IsOperator(const string& x)
{
   // Since the only impact of parentheses () is on precedence, 
   // they are not considered as operators here
   return ((x.length() == 1) &&
           (x[0] == '*' ||
            x[0] == '/' ||
            x[0] == '+' ||
            x[0] == '-'));
}

bool IsLeftParenthesis(const string& x)
{
   return x == "(";
}

bool IsRightParenthesis(const string& x)
{
   return x == ")";
}

bool IsOperand(const string& x)
{
   int y;
   stringstream ss(x);
   if (ss >> y) return true;
   else return false;
}

int GetPrecedence(const string& x)
{
   assert(IsOperator(x));
   if (x[0] == '*' || x[0] == '/') return 2;
   else return 1;
}

PNode CreateInfixTree(const string& exp)
{
   // create a dummy root with minimal precedence
   // its content is trivial
   PNode root = CreateNode("0");
   root->precedence = INT_MIN;

   // the previous operand of current operator
   PNode preOperand = NULL;
   // the previous operator of current operator
   PNode preOperator = root;
   // the impact of preceding parenthesis, if any
   int correction = 0;

   string token;
   stringstream ss(exp);

   while (ss >> token)
   {
      if (IsOperand(token))
      {
         preOperand = CreateNode(token);
      }
      else if (IsOperator(token))
      {
         PNode p = CreateNode(token);
         p->precedence = GetPrecedence(token) + correction;
         if (p->precedence > preOperator->precedence)
         {
            p->left = preOperand;
            preOperator->right = p;
            p->parent = preOperator;
         }
         else
         {
            preOperator->right = preOperand;
            PNode q = preOperator->parent;
            while (p->precedence <= q->precedence) q = q->parent;

            p->left = q->right;
            q->right = p;
            p->parent = q;
         }
         preOperand = NULL;
         preOperator = p;

      }//else if (IsOperator(token)
      else if (IsLeftParenthesis(token))
      {
         correction += 2;
      }
      else if (IsRightParenthesis(token))
      {
         correction -= 2;
      }
      else
      {
         cout << "illegal token found: " << token << endl;
         break;
      }
   }//while

   if (preOperand == NULL)
       cout << "illegal expression: cannot end with operator: "
            << preOperator->data << endl;
   else preOperator->right = preOperand;

   // delete dummy root
   PNode realRoot = root->right;
   delete root;
   if (realRoot) realRoot->parent = NULL;
   return realRoot;
}

void PostOrderPrintTree(PNode node)
{
   if (node)
   {
      PostOrderPrintTree(node->left);
      PostOrderPrintTree(node->right);
      cout << node->data << " ";
   }
}

int main()
{
   // valid operators: + - * / ( )
   // valid operands: integers
   // whitespace separated as: ( 1 + 2 ) * 3
   string exp;
   getline(cin, exp);
   PNode root = CreateInfixTree(exp);
   PostOrderPrintTree(root);
   cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Just as something to watch for, if you have an illegal expression, your algorithm will just keep going.

Comment: Also, this is pretty cool. From what you know of the algorithm, can it be made to handle unary operators and stuff?

Comment: @Seth, right, I didn't handle illegal expression too much at this phrase. For now it only supports binary operators and parenthesis though.

Comment: This is not C++ code, this is C code with a very small C++ coat.

Comment: @Sjoerd and there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Seth If you don't mind being fired...

Comment: @Sjoerd he never said he was doing this for an employer.

Comment: @Sjoerd, sorry that I didn't encapsulate them in a class. I just want drive the main algorithm quickly here:)

Comment: @Eric A C++ programmer would write the class definition without `typedef`, `struct Node` would be spelled without `struct`, `CreateNode` would be a constructor, and so on. This code is clearly written by a C programmer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is your stack:

```
while (p->precedence <= q->precedence) q = q->parent;
```

Comment: Ah ha! I know someone will say so :) I'm using a parent field in each node which doesn't necessarily save the memory compared to a stack.

Comment: The walking up step does behave like the pop operation of stack but it doesn't fully simulate all operations of a stack anyway. And it has advantage of not using another data structure besides a tree.